# Why or condition is working differently compare with Java and SQL

Tags: java, sql, if-statement, plsql, conditional-statements

In Java,

int a = 10, b = 10;

```
if (a == 10 || b==10)
{
// first condition (a==10) is true, so it wont check further
}
```

But, in SQL,

```
select * from my table where a = 10 or b = 10;

--As per my understanding, It should return data only based on a.
--But it returns both entries.
```

Why is that?

Comment: That's not how WHERE statements work. I assume what you're trying to do is get all rows where a=10 unless a!=10, then get all rows with b=10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing early termination - this means the second statement is only executed if the answer isn't already known, but it doesn't change the outcome (unless you execute an expression in the second statement).

So `a == 10 || b == 10` will result in anything where a, or b is 10 - or where a and b are 10. Or more precisely...

```
a = 10
b = 10
```

Or

```
a = 10
b = 0
```

Or

```
a = 0
b = 10
```

If a happens to be 10, you don't really need to check b - but some languages still do.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great comparison to make. However, it's not necessarily working any different. If you were to add

```
if (a == 10 || b==10)
{
// first condition (a==10) is true, so it wont check further
// return a or b
}
```

It would return every time where a or b is 10. Pretty much the same logic behind the SQL statement. 
The problem is with how you're misinterpreting `WHERE`, this will in fact return every record where a or b is 10.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in Java we are checking for a conditional logic and not aggregation like SQL is doing.

Java does short-circuiting meaning that if the first operand checked is true, it will not do the other operands.

In SQL the WHERE statements is looking for all `a` conditions and `b` conditions independently  since you are using `or`

Answer (score 1):

```
--As per my understanding, It should return data only based on a.
```

Your understanding is incorrect.  The query is internally optimized and you do not know what it is checking for first.  But it will check either condition, and then the other if necessary in order for it to be true.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not short-circuit logical expressions.  When you ask for records `WHERE A = 10 OR B = 10` you are asking for both - you're not asking for ones where the first case has been satisfied.

If you are wanting to emulate that short-circuit select logic, you can use this instead:

```
Select  *
From    Table
Where   A = 10
Or
(
    A <> 10
And B = 10
)
```

Comment: SQL *does* short-circuit logical expressions. The OP is just confused about how set-based processing works, that's all.